# ¿Por que no me imprime php en archivo html?

Tags: php

quería saber por que no me imprimí en array en el archivo html.

El array es:

```
<?php
    $productos = array();
    $productos[0]['insumo_solicitado']="NOTEBOOK BGH B1354F I3 6006U/4GB/HD500/14";
    $productos[0]['cantidad_pedida']=10;
    $productos[0]['precio_unitario']=15000;
    $productos[0]['descuento']="20 insumos o mas, 3% de Dto.15000";

    $productos[1]['insumo_solicitado'] = "TABLET 7 VIEWSONIC VIEWPAD AW7M BLACK";
    $productos[1]['cantidad_pedida'] =20;
    $productos[1]['precio_unitario'] =2099;
    $productos[1]['descuento'] = "20 insumos o mas, 10% de Dto.";
    $cntpr=count($productos);
?>
```

y el archivo html donde quiero imprimir el array es:

```
<?php 
                                        for ($i=0; $i<$cntpr;  $i++) { ?>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td> <?php echo $i;?> </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <img src='plugins/images/products/6fc3a4.jpg' width='45' height="45" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td> <?php echo $productos[$i]['insumo_solicitado'];?> </td>
                                            <td> <?php echo $productos[$i]['cantidad_pedida']; ?> </td>
                                            <td> <?php echo $productos[$i]['precio_unitario']; ?></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="text-success"><?php echo $productos[$i]['descuento']; ?> </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>$ 150000</td>
                                            <td>$ 0</td>
                                            <td>$ 150000</td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
```

El resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de ante mano, muchas gracias! de paso digo que me parece una tonteria no poder publicar por falta de detalle.

Comment: porque no estas usando un servidor web para ejecutar PHP,

Comment: porque no estas usando un servidor web para ejecutar PHP,

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Eso hice, y sigue igual..

Comment: Lo almacene en un servidor local http://localhost/primer_desempe%C3%B1o/orden_compra.html

Comment: El archivo donde ejecutas, el orden_compra.html debería de ser orden_compra.php para que lo puedas ejecutar.

Comment: Tampoco........